# Xampp localhost set up not opening in browser

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am working on setting up a localhost via xampp however, everything seems to be running fine. The only problem I get is when I am opening up the file via firefox. It does not open, instead it does a google search for the address I am typing.

Below is what I have in my httpd-vhost.config

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

DocumentRoot "C:/Users/angelramos/Dropbox/CUBIC IT Consulting/HTML File CUBIC IT/testbed"
  ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot "C:/Users/angelramos/Dropbox/CUBIC IT Consulting/HTML File CUBIC IT/testbed"
  ServerName localhost

CustomLog "C:/Users/angelramos/Dropbox/CUBIC IT Consulting/HTML File CUBIC IT/error.access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "C:/Users/angelramos/Dropbox/CUBIC IT Consulting/HTML File CUBIC IT/local.error.log"

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

This is what I have in my Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

And this is what I have in my httpd-ssl.config

```
Listen 443
```

SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3

I also changed the port to 85 in apache httpd.config to avoid apache server start errors.

IDK why one of the codes I paste above is not displaying properly. LMK if there is anything else I can do to make this easier. Thanks

Comment: Q: What exactly happens when you type `http://localhost:80` in your FF browser?  Q: What do your log files say 1) for starting Apache, and 2) when you try to access the page from a browser?

Comment: it says unable to connect. the folders i want to get to are located in the testbed folder so i ended the root directory in my httpd-vhost.config with the folder tested as part of the directory

Comment: When i type in localhost:85 it takes me to xampp dashboard. welcome to xampp. it is probably cause i set the listen in httpd.config to port 85

Comment: Beautiful - so you *can* connect (on port 85).  That's good :)  SUGGESTION: Try setting up a "virtual directory" for your testbed folder, using the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) httpd.conf directive: http://willi.am/blog/2011/02/24/creating-xampp-alias-directories/, https://gist.github.com/ralphcrisostomo/4974674

Comment: do i need to restart the laptop before testing the changes?

Comment: You need to restart Apache

Comment: I added     Alias C:/Users/angelramos/Dropbox/CUBICITConsulting/HTMLFileCUBICIT/testbed/
    <Directory "C:/Users/angelramos/Dropbox/CUBICITConsulting/HTMLFileCUBICIT/testbed/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: When I add that the apache won't start. I am assuming something is wrong with the code or directory I have?

Comment: [Sun Jan 10 23:47:13.990144 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 8340:tid 520] AH02538: Child: Parent process exited abruptly. Child process is ending
[Sun Jan 10 23:47:13.990144 2016] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 8340:tid 616] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[Sun Jan 10 23:47:13.990144 2016] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 8340:tid 524] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.

Comment: You're not looking at the right part of the error message to tell us the "root cause".  SUGGESTION: 1) reboot the PC, and see if Apache comes up correctly.  If not, then 2) Look at this link for an example log with the same "thread exit or an application request" ... and perhaps a completely different root cause.

Comment: Dont use Alias use a Virtual Host like you first started to do, [here is a post that should help you do that properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) It's aimed at WAMPServer users but everything is the same apart from the XAMPP directory structure

Comment: ok thank you so much, I am checking this.